# How to manage node.js request connection pool?

Tags: node.js, request

I am using node.js [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module to make multiple post requests.

Does this module have a connection pool ?

Can we manage this connection pool ?

can we close open connections ?

How do we handle the `socket hang up error`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Request does not have a connection pool. However, the [http module](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) (which request uses) does:

> In node 0.5.3+ there is a new implementation of the HTTP Agent which is used for pooling sockets used in HTTP client requests.

By default, there is a limit of 5 concurrent connections per host. There is [an issue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox/issues/116#issuecomment-15045187) with the current agent implementation that causes hang up errors to occur when you try to open too many connections.

You can either:

- increase the maximum number of connections: `http.globalAgent.maxSockets`.
- disable the agent entirely: pass `{pool: false}` to request.

There are several reasons for having an HTTP agent in the first place:

- it prevents you from accidentally opening thousands of connections to a host (would be perceived as an attack).
- connections in the pool will be kept opened for HTTP 1.1 keepalive.
- most of the time, `maxSockets` really depends on the host you're targetting. node.js will be perfectly happy to open 1000 concurrent connections if the other host handles it.

The behavior of the agent is explained in the node.js doc:

> The current HTTP Agent also defaults client requests to using Connection:keep-alive. If no pending HTTP requests are waiting on a socket to become free the socket is closed. This means that node's pool has the benefit of keep-alive when under load but still does not require developers to manually close the HTTP clients using keep-alive.

The asynchronous architecture of node.js is what makes it very cheap to open new connections.

Comment: What will be the consequences of setting {pool:false}. is it the right thing to do ? Who handles the closing of connections ? What is the max number I can give for maxSockets ?

Comment: OK, I added some explanations.

Comment: Thanks, could you also help me pointing to the source of all this informatio ?

Comment: In Node v0.12, `http.globalAgent.maxSockets` is Infinity.

Comment: As noted by @LucaSteeb, this answer seems to be out of date (if it was ever correct at all). The `http` module's docs list the default value of `agent.maxSockets` as Infinity, not 5 as claimed here.

Comment: in addition to maxSockets is set to infinity by default, keepAlive is set to false by default https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_new_agent_options